# How to save only new Highscore and put in Leaderboard

Tags: java, android, leaderboard

We usually use sharedpreferences to save current data like

```
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
            editor.putInt("Score", gamescore);       
            editor.putInt("Level", gamelevel);  
            editor.commit();
```

then use this to get the data that saved in sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
gamelifes = pref.getInt("Score", 0);
gamelevel = pref.getInt("Level", 0);
```

but as we know that saving will overwrite each time a new score is made.

How can I only save a new high score? i.e. If the user got score under latest high score it will not be saved, only if it is a new high score. Also, how can I put this score in the Google Leaderboard?

Comment: You can get the last high score and compare it to the new one.

Comment: You should always have the `high score` in memory somewhere. Try to read the highscore and store it when the app starts. And each time you are about to save it, compare with the one in memory, save it if its more and also assign it to the highscore in memory. 
Should be simple.

Comment: @Panther  so it's like compare the current score with the highscore is more high or lower right? have some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand the code but i think you are looking to use an if statement

```
highscore = pref.getInt('Highscore", 0);
if (gamescore > highscore){
    pref.edit("Highscore, gamescore);
}
```

something like that